# C# connection to DB2 - unknown sql type -370 for XML type

Tags: c#, xml, db2, odbc

I'm connecting to a DB2 database using the `OdbcConnection` using C#. I'm connecting, making queries, etc. and all is going well until I query for a field of which the data type is XML. I get an error back stating `Unknown SQL type - -370`. I've found restrictions with the .NET ODBC driver on LOB fields ([here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.doc/doc/r0011829.html)) but the error codes are -98 (LOB), -99 (CLOB) and -350 (DBCLOB). There is a workaround suggesting I add `LONGDATACOMPAT=1` to my connectionstring but this is not working for -370. Does anyone know how I can get past this issue?

Comment: Have you checked out this example: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sample.doc/doc/dotnet_cs/s-XmlRead-cs.html

Comment: That is perfect, thanks! Only problem I have now is that the xml is larger than the maximum length of varchar but that's an issue for another time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

mustaccio's link ([here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sample.doc/doc/dotnet_cs/s-XmlRead-cs.html)) provided the solution.

Comment: "Unknown SQL type - -98"  hi @bixarrio and mustaccio, I looked up your link but couldn't able to fix the problem. Can you please give more details?

Comment: What is the solution? I did not find the link helpful.

Comment: This part; `XMLSERIALIZE(info as varchar(600)) AS INFO` on the XML data provided my solution

Answer (score 1):

With `XMLSERIALIZE` in the query and `LONGDATACOMPAT=1` in the connection string (as mentioned above), I was able to get large (>100KB) XML from fields using the CLOB data type.  Something like this worked for me:

```
var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = 
    "SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(xmlfield AS CLOB(10M)) AS xmlfield FROM [table] WHERE [condition]";
using (command)
{
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var foo = !reader.IsDBNull(0) ? reader.GetString(0) : null;
            //do stuff...
        }
    }
}
```

I've set the maximum CLOB size to 10 megabytes, which is a safe ceiling for my project.  See [IBM's page on XMLSERIALIZE](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0022194.html?pos=2) for more info.